# Using TC_CALENDAR from within a PHP file

Tags: php, calendar

in my php file, inside the body section I have

```
<?php 
//get class into the page
<require_once('calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');?>
```

then I use this code

```
<?php
$myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1", true, false);
$myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
$myCalendar->setDate($dt, $mn, $yr);      
$myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");    
$myCalendar->setYearInterval(2010, 2030);     
$myCalendar->dateAllow('2010-01-01', '2030-12-31');   
$myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');      
$myCalendar->writeScript();?>
```

When I run the php, i get a calendar.
I can change the year and month, and the calendar is updated accordingly.
But when i pick (click on) a day for the displayed year/month ..... nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can we have a link to the documentation of this calendar library you're using please? Don't assume we all know everything about your random library. Thanks.

Comment: `when i pick (click on) a day for the displayed year/month ..... nothing happens`...so what were you expecting to happen? It's not really clear.

Comment: The calendar has i small '?' in the top left corner. when clicked, it displays "localized DatePicker version 3.74".

Comment: By default, just left of the calendar icon, I have todays date (like "Oct 20 2021"). I was hoping that, by opening the calender and selecting another day, this date would be adapted, so I can pick it up from withing the PHP code for processing.

Comment: Can you reply to my first comment as well, please. Otherwise there's not much we can do for you

Comment: This is the only link that i can provide : http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php. I don't know if there is a real documentation to be found out there....

Comment: You mean you want it to be like the "DatePicker Style" example from that page? Also further down the page is a "How to get the value?" example which probably answers your question anyway. If it doesn't, then please make clear in what way it's inadequate for your needs.